# scanf and wrong input makes output wierd

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int var();
int var()
{
    return 10;
}
 
void main()
{
    int a;
    double x;
    a=0;
    a=var();
    printf("hello world, i am a function which returned the value %d",a);
    printf("\nnow you enter a value:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    
    printf("so you entered the value: %d",a);
    printf("\nnow enter a double value:");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("The double number till 4 precision is: %0.4lf",x);
}
```

When I input normal integer and double values for the two scanf it runs fine. However I want to make it more robust. If I enter a decimal value for int scanf the code jumps directly to the next printf and skips the scanf for double. It prints the decimal part that I have input in the int as the double value.

eg:

> hello world, i am a function which returned the value 10
>
> now you enter a value:44.67
>
> so you entered the value: 44
>
> now enter a double
> value:The double number till 4 precision is: 0.6700

Any help?

Comment: Read the manual page for scanf - it returns a value!

Comment: @EdHeal , But that won't help in this case as both the `scanf`s will return 1. Checking this is good,though...

Comment: When you input `44.67`, the first `scanf` consumes `44`. The second `scanf` sees the `.67` and consumes it as it is a valid decimal number . This is why the second `scanf` gets "skipped"

Comment: Perhaps a better pattern for scanf is required

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf`, eg: `if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) /* error */;`

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky because a number with fractions (like e.g `12.34`) do have a valid *integer* part, which is read and correctly parsed by the first `scanf` call.

The simplest solution is to use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read the input into a buffer, and then use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) on that buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the function `fpurge()` to erase any input or output buffered in the given stream (which is `stdin` in this case).
Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int var();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a;
  double x;

  a = 0;
  a = var();

  printf("Hello world, I am a function which returned the value %d.\n", a);
  printf("Now you enter a value: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("So, you entered the value %d.\n", a);
  printf("Now enter a double value: ");
  fpurge(stdin);
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  printf("The double number till 4 precision is %.4lf.\n", x);

  return 0;
} // End main

int var() {
  return 10;
}
```

Here is the output which I got:

> Hello world, I am a function which returned the value 10.
>  Now you
>   enter a value: 44.67
>  So, you entered the value 44.
>  Now enter
>   a double value: 3.14159
>  The double number till 4 precision is
>   3.1416.

Comment: Thang thanks for the reply. It worked. But one more question.
When i used the fflush(stdin) it didnot gave me a desired output but fpurge did ?? why ??

Comment: @Magnum Don't use fflush(stdin). Read more here http://www.cprogramming.com/faq/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1052863818